# React native change input value real time

Tags: react-native, textinput

I'm new to react native. I'm making a screen which has three TextInputs, when an user types a number in the first and the second TextInput, On the third input the total of the first and second inputs will be showing

I'm trying to do it but it's not working

```
this.state = {
      Length: 0,
      Piece1: 0,
      Piece2: 0,   
};
onPiece1(Piece1) {
    this.setState({ Piece1 });
  }
  onPiece2(Piece2) {
    this.setState({ Piece2 });
  }

onLength() {
    const { Length, Piece1, Piece2} = this.state;
    let piece1 = this.setState({ Piece1 });
    let piece2 = this.setState({ Piece2 });

    const Balance =
      Number(Length) -
      Number(piece1) +
      Number(piece2) 
    this.setState({ Length: Balance });
  }

<Block margin={[theme.sizes.base, 0]} padding={[10]}>
                      <Input
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        label="Piece 1"
                        value={`${this.state.Piece1}`}
                        onChangeText={this.onPiece1}
                        style={[styles.input]}
                      />
                    </Block>
                    {/* piece 2 */}
                    <Block margin={[theme.sizes.base, 0]} padding={[10]}>
                      <Input
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        label="Piece 2"
                        value={`${this.state.Piece2}`}
                        style={[styles.input]}
                        onChangeText={this.onPiece2}
                      />
                    </Block>
                  </Block>
<Block margin={[theme.sizes.base, 0]} padding={[10]}>
                      <Input
                        label="Balance"
                        selectTextOnFocus={false}
                        style={[styles.input]}
                        value={`${this.state.Length}`}
                        onChangeText={this.onLength}
                      />
                    </Block>
```

Answer (score 0):

you code works only when you start type in  3rd text input...
so call onLength function on both onPiece1 and onPiece2 function